# Cannot select framework to use in new web application using Netbeans on Ubuntu

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, jakarta-ee, netbeans-6.9

Using Netbeans 6.9.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 Beta, when I try to create a new web application, none of checkboxes on the frameworks page are selectable.  Here are my exact steps:

1. File > New Project
2. Choose Java Web from Categories and Web Application from Projects, and click Next
3. Accept the defaults on the Name and Location page, and click Next
4. Accept the defaults on the Server and Settings page (Server: GlassFish Server 3; Java EE Version: Java EE 6 Web, and click Next

On the Frameworks page, 6 options appear with checkboxes (Google Web Toolkit, Spring Web MVC, Echo2...), but I can't figure out how to check one.  I *can* do it on my Windows machine running the same version of Netbeans.  I have all available plugins installed in Netbeans.

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI: I *can* add a framework after-the-fact from the Project Properties dialog.

Comment: The same problem happens on NetBeans 6.7.

Comment: It also happens for checkbox controls in several different areas in NetBeans, besides selecting a framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of searching, I found a solution.
In my case it seemed to be open-jdk that was causing the issue...

I wrote the solutions down here:
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191959

hope it helps...
dGo

Comment: Thanks, dGo.  Switching to Sun's distribution worked for me too. Here are the tweaks I made for my environment: First, I used "maverick" in lieu of "lucid" when adding a new APT repository.  Then I added sun-java6-jdk when doing an apt-get.  Last, I removed the --jdkhome switch in my Netbeans shortcut which pointed to openjdk.  My Netbeans config file was pointing to Sun's JDK by default, but I had never installed it.  Thanks again for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Try this : first, create your project without selecting a framework, then choose the framework you want to use in its properties.

Comment: That works, but it's still just a workaround to the real problem.  I should be able to set the checkboxes here, as I can on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... after many attempts to fix this i removed netbeans from the software center, installed it manually.. and now it all works smooth :D

I do believe that netbeans from the repo is 6.9 though and i installed 6.9.1 (on ubuntu 10.10)

Also I installed the sun java sdk:  sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I ran into the same problem and finally figured out how to resolve it

Go to Tools > Plugins > Installed Plugins (Tab)

You will find the following plugins there

- Java SE
- Java ME
- Groovy
- Base IDE
- Java Web and EE

Ensure that Java SE, Base IDE, Java Web and EE plugins are active, if not activate them. You should all set from there.

Comment: Can't find Java ME, Groovy & Java Web and EE plugins. Tried searching in Available Plugins did not work there either